# Can't get SSH connections through AWS Session Manager working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm, aws-session-manager

I have an EC2 instance in a private subnet in which I want to copy files.

Instead of a S3 bucket I want to use Secure File Copy through Session Manager as documented on [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-getting-started-enable-ssh-connections.html) and announced on [here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/07/session-manager-launches-tunneling-support-for-ssh-and-scp/?nc1=h_ls).

A running EC2 instance is attached with an instance profile containing the policy `AmazonEC2RoleforSSM`. On my local machine (macOS 10.14.5) the AWS CLI (aws-cli/1.16.195) and the Session Manager Plugin (1.1.26.0) is installed and `.ssh/config` is configured accordingly.

- I can log into the instance with Session Manager on the web AWS Console.
- I can log into the instance using the CLI with `aws ssm start-session --target i-XXX`.
- I can't log into the instance using SSH. I've tried 2 different OpenSSH client versions:

**OpenSSH_7.9p1:**

When I run `ssh ec2-user@i-XXX` it hangs infinitely. However I can see an `connected` session in the Session Manager. When I SIGTERM the process I  get following output and the session is terminated:

```
Command '['session-manager-plugin', '{"SessionId": "XXX", "TokenValue": "XXX", "StreamUrl": "wss://ssmmessages.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/v1/data-channel/XXX?role=publish_subscribe", "ResponseMetadata": {"RetryAttempts": 0, "HTTPStatusCode": 200, "RequestId": "XXX", "HTTPHeaders": {"x-amzn-requestid": "XXX", "date": "Wed, 07 Aug 2019 08:47:23 GMT", "content-length": "579", "content-type": "application/x-amz-json-1.1"}}}', 'eu-central-1', 'StartSession', u'cc', '{"DocumentName": "AWS-StartSSHSession", "Target": "i-XXX", "Parameters": {"portNumber": ["22"]}}', u'https://ssm.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com']' returned non-zero exit status -13
```

**OpenSSH_8.0p1:**

When I run `ssh ec2-user@i-XXX` I get the following error and need to manually terminate the session in the Session Manager:

```
kex_exchange_identification: banner line contains invalid characters
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just got an answer from AWS Support and it working for me now. There was a bug in one of the following components.

Ensure at least following versions and it should work then.

**local**

- aws cli: aws-cli/1.16.213 Python/3.7.2 Darwin/18.7.0 botocore/1.12.203

  - `aws --version`
- session-manager-plugin: 1.1.26.0

  - `session-manager-plugin --version`

**target ec2 instance**

- amazon-ssm-agent:  2.3.687.0

  - for AmazonLinux `yum info amazon-ssm-agent | grep "^Version"`

I've also created a neat SSH ProxyCommand script that temporary adds your public ssh key to target instance during connection to target instance.

- AWS SSM SSH ProxyComand -> https://gist.github.com/qoomon/fcf2c85194c55aee34b78ddcaa9e83a1